# Understanding Classical Contributions to the Quantum Field Theory Path Integral

Tags: quantum-field-theory, particle-physics, feynman-diagrams, path-integral, correlation-functions

I'm a data scientist with no physics background who sometimes reads about physics in my spare time, so please take it easy on me, I know these are really obvious questions to physicists but feel free to fix up any misunderstandings I have as I frame my questions (I'm certain there will be plenty).

I'm trying to understand the calculation of the path integral for a free scalar field with a source term,
$$Z(J) = \int D\phi\, e^{iS[\phi(x)] + i\int d^4x \, J(x) \phi(x)}$$
After some manipulation (involving completing the square, obtaining the inverse of the differential operator, etc.) we get the expression:
$$Z(J) = \int D\phi \, e^{iS[\phi(x) - \int d^4x \, D(x - y)J(x)] + i\frac{1}{2} \int d^4y \int d^4x \, J(y) D(x - y) J(x)}$$
So $\int d^4x \, D(x - y)J(x)$ becomes the new 'mean' of the distribution, and since $\int d^4x \, D(x - y)J(x) = \phi(x)_c$ (the classical field, I'm guessing?), we get:
$$\begin{align*}
Z(J) &= \int D\phi \, e^{iS[\phi(x) - \phi(x)_c] + i\frac{1}{2} \int d^4y \, J(y) \phi(x)_c} \\
&= e^{i\frac{1}{2}\int d^4y \, J(y) \phi(x)_c} \times \int D\phi \, e^{iS[\phi(x) - \phi(x)_c]}
\end{align*}$$
Right? So the classical field becomes the 'average' field configuration. And since a shift in the mean of a Gaussian doesn't change the total amplitude, the second term is just the usual normalisation constant, which gets divided out anyway, so the expression becomes:
$$\begin{align*}
Z(J) &= \int D\phi \, e^{iS[\phi(x) - \phi(x)_c]} \times e^{i\frac{1}{2} \int d^4y \, J(y) \phi(x)_c} \\
&= N \times e^{i\frac{1}{2}\int d^4y \, J(y) \phi(x)_c}
\end{align*}$$
We can then expand the $e^{i\frac{1}{2}\int d^4y \, J(y) \phi(x)_c} = e^{i\frac{1}{2} \int d^4y \int d^4x \, J(y) D(x - y) J(x)}$
term as a series and evaluate it perturbatively, and the resulting terms become contributions to Feynman diagrams.

I guess as someone who learns about this on the side, I'm trying to gain some conceptual understanding of what's going on here, as opposed to rigorous mathematical mastery.

Q1: So is it the case that we divide out the vacuum-to-vacuum amplitude with no source (the normalisation constant), and are left with only the total classical interaction energy $J\phi_c$ contributing to the final amplitude?

Q2: If so, why does the classical field make an appearance here? What happens to the 'quantumness'? As far as I can tell the quantum fluctuations around the classical configuration get absorbed into the normalisation constant, so we're basically left with a classical field. I'm not sure if this has anything to do with taking the classical limit, which other related questions tackle, we are still doing the full path integral here.

Q3: Is the propagator term $D(x - y)$ (which is also a correlation function) really an amplitude? I'm asking this from a path integral perspective, as in is there a way to infer that $D(x - y)$ is something like an amplitude for a process without resorting to the canonical formalism? Obviously, it *contributes* to the final amplitude, but so does the variance $\sigma^2$ in the general Gaussian probability distribution in the presence of a term like $J$, but we don't say $\sigma^2$ itself is a probability. It seems very different than the propagator for a single particle in regular QM. My intuition is that since these terms are contributing to an amplitude, we can infer that they are amplitudes themselves, but not sure how accurate this is.

Q4: This is probably the question that is bugging me the most, but how do particles emerge from this framework? Are they just words we drape around the perturbative terms in the expansion? Or do they have actual physical significance? They don't seem to be the same kind of point particles as in regular QM. Once again trying to get this from a purely path integral point of view, I understand in the canonical formalism particles can roughly be conceptualised as excited states of the momentum modes of the quantum free scalar field $|p>$, which we can then superimpose to create 'almost' delta distributions in position space $|x>$, representing the amplitude of finding something like an excited quantum harmonic oscillator at that point. But from a path integral perspective, the particles seem to be very related to Green's functions of the classical field or something, it just seems weird.

Any help with any of these questions would be thoroughly appreciated by a stranger. Thank you.

Comment: Are you familiar with the framework of generating functionals? If not, I would strongly suggest to dig deeper into it. Your calculations are sloppy, already by pulling out the field of the source term from the path integral by saying it's classical. What you're really doing is generating 1(n)-point functions.

Comment: I’ve encountered generating functionals but definitely not an expert. In terms of pulling out the source term I’m just using the identity in Schwartz’ book, and then after I’m noticing it may be able to be expressed as a classical field with the source, but not 100% sure (hence why I’m here asking).

Comment: Note that Schwartz only ever talks about free particles, never classical. Indeed if you take your equation with the classical field and compare it to a hard perturbation around the classical field, you will notice that you miss the fluctuation in the source term, which is the "quantumness" you miss I guess. Note, though, that I'm not an expert either.